# Array of rounded buttons

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, rounded-corners

fairly new to coding still. I found on SO a post about how to make a button with rounded corners. It advised to create an outlet -call it say "roundedButton"- and use the following code:

```
CALayer *btnLayer = [roundedButton layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

I have tried this and it works fine. In my project I have many buttons that all need rounded corners though. I tried creating an outlet collection, called it "arrayOfButtons", but the method

```
CALayer *btnLayer = [arrayOfButtons layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

doesn't work. I know I could do the rounding of the corners one by one, but there's got to be a faster way. Anyone knows how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Just loop through the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (UIButton *roundedButton in arrayOfButtons)
{
  CALayer *btnLayer = roundedButton.layer;
  [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
}
```

Comment: `arrayOfButtons` will be an `NSArray`. Just do: `for (UIButton *roundedButton in arrayOfButtons) {` and `CALayer *btnLayer = roundedButton.layer;`.

Comment: @rmaddy Good addition.

Comment: It's not an addition, it's a correction. Your original code won't work for the `NSArray`.

Comment: The loop code you had originally would only have worked if the buttons were in a fixed-sized C array of buttons.